# Blocked Mixed Content EC2 HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

My architecture is the following on my Beanstalk Environment...

1. AWS Application Load Balancer

   1.1 SSL Certificate
2. NodeJS Environment

   2.1 React App

   2.2 NodeJS Server

I have my load balancer redirecting every request to https. Everything inside my nodejs environment is in plain http. My problem is that when my react app is making a call to my node server, I get "Blocked mixed content at http://localhost:3000/user/login" on my browser. Is there a way around this or the only solution is to make the server https as well?

Thank you